# Adjust the position of block

Tags: html, positioning

I'd like to have a block of html with a description and a block of content.

I have the following code.

```
<div id="bloc">
    <span style="display:inline-block"> Description </span>
    <span> Long content ... </span>
</div>
```

This produce something like:

```
descr : conent .....
end of content
```

But i'd prefer have something like.

```
descr : content ......
        end of content
```

How to prevent the extra content to go under the descr?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a semantic point of view, you can better use `div's` with `float` left/right.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7GW5M/).

Comment: Indeed, but you should add a width for the floating div, else they go on different lines.